# How does CA SiteMinder web agent work with IIS?

Tags: single-sign-on, siteminder

Installed SiteMinder web agent(ca-wa-IIS7-12.0-sp3-cr010-win64.exe) in windows server 2008 r2, and IIS version 7.5. There are 2 web sites(A,B) under the IIS server, while the agent only targets to one web site A(select one website during install). I do not have a valid policy server, so input fake IP during configuration of web agent.

Then access A in browser, there is error as expected, but access B in browser, server also returns an error. CA related http modules can be seen registered in A site in IIS. none CA SiteMinder related things in Module or Handler in B site of IIS. so How does CA SiteMinder web agent work with IIS? and is it able to process request event not resisted in IIS? is there a way that only apply SSO to only one website of server with many websites?

Answer (score 2):

That version was buggy. use CR12 if 12.0 SP3 Pollicy Server. If 12.5 or later use the 12.5 or later agent.

that version has the classic 6 embedded and a new module for the new pipline.

this type of question really should be answered with "go take a class, ca has many" because you did not specify a problem and thus there is no real issue to address and assist with.

Comment: Thanks very much! I did read many articles on CA web site, but did not find where they say the web agent version is buggy and does not support scenario mentioned in question, will you please provide the link?

Comment: You probably won't find much information on CA's website about their products being buggy.  You will need to hear that from people that use the products everyday.